# Mangento 2: How to get language swicher using getChildHtml()?

Tags: magento2.3

**For minicart:**

(a) Reference name: minicart

(b) as : minicart, 
so getChildHtml('minicart')

**For top search:**

(a) Reference name: top.search

(b) as : topSearch,

so getChildHtml('topSearch')

**The above is done by me, but I need to get a language switcher.**

**What is a reference name for language switcher & store switcher ?**

Comment: reference name for language switcher is `store_language` and `store_switcher` for store switcher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For language dropdown**

getChildHtml('store_language') ?>

The language dropdown will be shown if you create a **store view** from the admin panel.

**For store_switcher**

getChildHtml('store_switcher') ?>

The store dropdown will be shown if you create a **store** from the admin panel.